# Importing Contact .VCF to phonebook android

Tags: android, android-intent, contacts, android-contacts, start-activity

I am creating a app where i need to **backup** and **restore** contacts programmatically to and from my website.

Here i have completed one part(backup contacts).

In the other part(importing contacts) i use this code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new     File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"Contacts.vcf")),"text/x-vcard"); //storage path is path of your vcf file and vFile is name of that file.
startActivity(intent);
```

This code works 90% perfectly,only one problem is that when this code gets called a alert dialogue gets displayed and we have to manually select where to restore the contacts.

e.g Phone,email id

How can i make it auto called,so that whenever this code gets called Contacts gets restored automatically to Phone memory ?

Answer (score 1):

You can `insert` or `import` contacts via [ContactProvider](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/06/18/add-contact-programmatically-android/) class.

Comment: ya this seem tobe fine,but how can i parse .vcf file, so that i can insert contacts from it ?